# $n$th derivative of function $\frac{1}{(1-2x)^2}$

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

I am trying to find the $n$th derivative of the function $\frac{1}{(1-2x)^2}$.
The first three are simple but I can't see a schema right now.
\begin{align*}
y^{\prime} & = \frac{4}{(1-2x)^3}\\ 
y^{\prime\prime} & = \frac{24}{(1-2x)^4}\\ 
y^{\prime\prime\prime} & = -\frac{192}{(1-2x)^5}
\end{align*}

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not gonna put an answer right now, because I haven't put much thought into it, but there is a pattern for the top numbers. 4 = 1 * 4, 24 = 4 * 6, 192 = 24 * 8. If T(n) is the numerator of the nth derivative, then T(n) = T(n-1) * 2(n + 1)

Comment: with a $(-1)^n$ in front...

Comment: It is just $(n+1)!2^n(1-2x)^{-(n+2)}$.

Answer (score 2):

You did a mistke with you last derivative, it is $y^{\prime\prime\prime}= \frac{192}{(1-2x)^5}$. You can notice that :
$$y'=y\frac{4}{1-2x}$$
$$y''=y'\frac{6}{1-2x}$$
$$y'''=y''\frac{8}{1-2x}$$
So we you can try to prove by induction that $y^{(n+1)}=y^{(n)}\frac{2(n+2)}{1-2x}$.

Once you have done this, you can conclude that $$y^{(n)}=\frac{\prod_{i=2}^{n+1} 2i}{(1-2x)^{n+2}}=\frac{2^{n}\prod_{i=2}^{n+1} i}{(1-2x)^{n+2}}=\frac{2^{n}(n+1)!}{(1-2x)^{n+2}}$$

Comment: Edited with your remark :)

Comment: If you don't want to have the $\prod$, you could say that $y^{(n)}=\frac{2^{n}*(n+1)!}{(1-2x)^{n+2}}$